# Perl DBI connection to PostgreSQL doesn't die() on database error

Tags: perl, postgresql, error-handling

I am used to Perl "crashing" my script when a SQL goes bad, but Postgres is just giving the error to the Apache error log and the script continues. Evil behaviour for debugging code.

Now I have asked the Oracle of Google but either I am asking the wrong questions or, very unlikely, I am the only one with that problem. ;)

In Short: I want the same fault behaviour with Postgres as MySQL does, ie, "crash" the script and take heed of `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` and just show me the faulty SQL statement.

I am using good old `DBI` to access the PG-DB, Postgres 8.4 and Perl 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 on my server, if that matters. All packages are from the official rep.

EDIT:
Thanks to Richard Huxton this is solved, leaving the solution for others to find.

```
our $dbh = DBI->connect($DBUrl, $DBUser, $DBPass,{ RaiseError => 1}
           ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you just need to set RaiseError when you make the connection?

https://metacpan.org/module/DBI

Comment: Thanks, that was it. No clue why that is the default behaviour with MySQL but not with Postgres.

Comment: I didn't think it was on by default with any DBI driver. Docs seem to suggest off is the default

Comment: Nope, never defined that when using MySQL. Very strange indeed. o.o